# $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\sup a_n:=a>b\implies$ $a_{n_0}>b$

Tags: calculus

Let $\{a_n\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}_+$ be an increasing sequence of nonnegative real numbers. Suppose that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\sup a_n:=a>b$$ where $b\ge 0$. I must prove that exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n_0}>b$, this fact is quite intuitive, but I wanted to show it formally.

Fix $\varepsilon = b/2$, then exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$a_{n_0}>a-\frac{b}{2}>b-\frac{b}{2}=\frac{b}{2}$$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try concrete examples. Like $a_n=100-\frac1n$, $a=100$, and $b=99.99$. See if you can find your mistake now.

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong?  It isn't what you wanted to prove, perhaps, but that just means you chose $\epsilon$ poorly.  Try $\epsilon =\frac {a-b}2$.

Comment: Maybe try a proof by contradiction?  If the conclusion didn't hold, then you would have for all $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ that $a_{n_0} \le b$, so from that you can conclude that $\sup a_n$ ...

Answer (score 3):

Take $\epsilon = a-b$ then $a-a_{n_0}=|a_{n_0}-a|<a-b$ which implies $a_{n_0} > b$.